# Find rows indexes with zero values

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a (N,2) array representing some image coordinates. I want to extract only those rows where two values are zero.

For example in this array:

```
aux = np.array([[0.,-0.0001], [0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0], [123,0.0]])
```

I want as result a numpy array indicating whole row have zeros:

**result: np.array([1,2])**

Until now, Im triyng with [where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
np.where(aux==0)
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]))
```

But I don't understant the output as a tuple. What is the second array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using `np.all`:

```
np.all(aux == 0, axis=1)
```

This returns a boolean array of where your two values are `0`:

```
array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

You can extract an array of the corresponding indices (matching your desired output) using `np.where`:

```
np.where(np.all(aux == 0, axis=1))

(array([1, 2]),)
```

Answer (score 2):

using Lambdas in Python you can solve it like this:

```
aux = np.array ([[0., - 0.0001], [0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0], [123,0.0]])
```

First, you must define the logic with a lambda expression,
The condition you are looking for is:

```
f = lambda x: x [0]==0 and x [1] == 0
```

map () is a python function that applies the lambda expression to each element

```
map (f, aux)
```

the output will be a Boolean vector with True where the condition has been met

```
[False, True, True, False]
```

This works fine for Python 2.7, but not in Python 3.6.

for python 3.6, you will need an additional step:

```
iter = map (f, aux)

for item in iter
   print (item)
```

and you will get the same result:

```
False
True
True
False
```